# Can we find the neighbors of all vertices in a graph without a loop using R?

Tags: r, graph, igraph, complex-networks

Can we find the common neighbors of all pairs of vertices in a graph without a loop using R?

For example we use the following command to find the common neighbors of node 1 and 2 in the TD1 graph:

`intersect(neighborhood(graph=TD1,order=1,nodes=1),neighborhood(graph=TD1,order=1,nodes=2))`

But I need to find the common neighbors of every pairs of vertices and because the graph is large using a loop is very time consuming! Is there function for this procedure?

Answer (score 2):

we can use the adjacency graph to get a sparse matrix showing the connections. Then, convert it into data.table for joining by neighbours. Then, concatenate neighbours by pairs of vertices where vertices are not the same and also where pairs of vertices are not repeated

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)
numVer <- 5
g <- erdos.renyi.game(numVer, 1)
plot(g)

adjSM <- as(get.adjacency(g), "dgTMatrix")
adjDT <- data.table(V1=adjSM@i+1, V2=adjSM@j+1)
res <- adjDT[adjDT, nomatch=0, on="V2", allow.cartesian=TRUE
             ][V1 < i.V1, .(Neighbours=paste(V2, collapse=",")),
               by=c("V1","i.V1")][order(V1)]
res
```

Comment: this works great. However, when `adjDT` get very large, I run into `data.table`'s `Error in vecseq(f__,` . In this case, can we set `by=.EACHI`? If so, does it go after `allow.cartesion=TRUE`?

Comment: wah you are going to deal with a huge dataset. Are you sure abt this? It might hang your computer

Comment: Yeah! My `adjDT` holds over 8 million rows and 2 columns. Working on a 128GB Windows 10 machine. Does this work? If so, where exactly do I place `by=.EACHI`? Or are there alternatives to do this more efficiently / in steps? Many thanks, Chinsoon12!!

Comment: if i am not wrong, the `by=.EACHI` is still not going to work because it will go beyond the memory limit. You can try if you still want (just put it infront of allow.carteisn)