# R - joining more than 2^31 rows with data.table

Tags: r, merge, data.table, igraph

I have an `igraph` network graph with 103,887 nodes and 4,795,466 ties.

This can be structured as an edgelist in a `data.table` with almost 9 million rows.

I can find the common neighbors in this network, following @chinsoon12's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788471/can-we-find-the-neighbors-of-all-vertices-in-a-graph-without-a-loop-using-r). See the example below.

This works beautifully for smaller networks, but runs into problems in my use-case because **the merge results in more than 2^31 rows**.

Questions:

- Are there efficient alternatives on how to deal with this?
- Can I split the data and do the computation in steps? The results will be used to query about common neighbors.

Example - modified from @chinsoon12's answer:

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)
g <- random.graph.game(10, p=0.10)

adjSM <- as(get.adjacency(g), "dgTMatrix")
adjDT <- data.table(V1=adjSM@i+1, V2=adjSM@j+1)

res <- adjDT[adjDT, nomatch=0, on="V2", allow.cartesian=TRUE
][V1 < i.V1, .(Neighbours=paste(V2, collapse=",")),
  by=c("V1","i.V1")][order(V1)]

res

   V1 i.V1 Neighbours
1:  4    5          8
2:  4   10          8
3:  5   10          8
```

Comment: I think you can check the max number of rows supported by your machine, i.e., `.Machine$integer.max`. In my machine, it is `> log2(.Machine$integer.max)
[1] 31`, which means i cannot have more than `2^31` rows...

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding This is the same for me, but there might be a neat way of dealing with this, right?

Comment: Do you mean dealing with the size limitation issue or the speed issue of my solution? I don't think the size limitation issue can be addressed if you really have more than 2^31 rows, but it is possible for the second issue.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding the size limitation issue is the same for me. While I like your answer, the performance issue of your approach prohibits its use in real-life.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I will have a look at the possible improvement of my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

- If you just want to query the common neighbors, I don't suggest you build up a huge look-up table. Instead, you can use the following code to get the result for your query:

```
find_common_neighbors <- function(g, Vs) {
  which(colSums(distances(g, Vs) == 1) == length(Vs))
}
```

such that

```
> find_common_neighbors(g, c(4, 8))
integer(0)

> find_common_neighbors(g, c(4, 5))
[1] 8
```

- If you need a look-up table, an alternative is to use `Neighbours` as the key to search its associated node, e.g.,

```
res <- transform(
  data.frame(Neighbours = which(degree(g) >= 2)),
  Nodes = sapply(
    Neighbours,
    function(x) toString(neighbors(g, x))
  )
)
```

---

## Previous Answer

I think you can use `ego` over `g` directly to generate `res`, e.g.,

```
setNames(
  data.frame(
    t(do.call(
      cbind,
      lapply(
        Filter(function(x) length(x) > 2, ego(g, 1)),
        function(x) {
          rbind(combn(x[-1], 2), x[1])
        }
      )
    ))
  ),
  c("V1", "V2", "Neighbours")
)
```

which gives

```
  V1 V2 Neighbours
1  4  5          8
2  4 10          8
3  5 10          8
```

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. While this gives the right answers, this approach seems too slow for the use-case. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: @wake_wake See my update.

Comment: I like this new approach! Thank you! Is it possible to have the output structured as "Node 1, Node 2, Common Neighbor(s)" - like your earlier suggestion?

Comment: @wake_wake If we save the result in a data frame with columns `Node1`, `Node2` and `Neighbor`, we may need an extremely large data frame, which is also a time-consuming process to generate it since `combn` will take a super long time.

Answer (score 2):

> common neighbors
>
> Can I split the data and do the computation in steps?

You can split by V1 to avoid running into the big-merge issue:

```
neighDT = adjDT[, if (.N > 1) {
    cb = combn(V2, 2)
    .(a = cb[1, ], b = cb[2, ])
}, by=.(neighbor = V1)]
```

which gives

```
   neighbor a  b
1:        8 4  5
2:        8 4 10
3:        8 5 10
```

(The OP found `gRbase::combnPrim` to be faster than `combn` here.)

> How can we collapse all the common neighbors (separated with a comma) for the same combination into one observation?

```
neighDT_agg = neighDT[order(neighbor), 
  .(neighbors = toString(neighbor))
, keyby=.(a,b)]
```

The `order` ensures that the string is sorted alphabetically. The `keyby` ensures that the table is sorted by pairs {a,b} and facilitates a simple fast lookup for multiple pairs at once:

```
# single query
neighDT_agg[.(4,10), neighbors]
# [1] "8"

# multi query
pairs_queryDT = data.table(a = c(4,5,8), b = c(5,10,10))
neighDT_agg[pairs_queryDT, neighbors]
[1] "8" "8" NA
```

---

> I have an igraph network graph with 103,887 nodes and 4,795,466 ties.

Each call to `combn` will be making a 2-by-`choose(.N, 2)` matrix. If a node is connected to all other nodes, then it is a common neighbor to all pairs of other nodes and you'll be facing `choose(103887-1, 2)` of these pairs. I guess this is more an issue with the way the problem is defined than with the approach to solving it.

---

> The results will be used to query about common neighbors.

For the approach above, you'll need to compute the full neighbors table first.

If you just have a few ad hoc queries about intersecting neighbors:

```
find_neighbors <- function(a, b){
    adjDT[.(c(a, b)), on=.(V1), V2[duplicated(V2)]]
}

find_neighbors(4, 10)
# [1] 8
```

This can similarly be wrapped in `toString` to collapse the values.

Comment: Thanks! The first piece of code works pretty fast, especially using gRbase::combnPrim.  How can we collapse all the common neighbors (separated with a comma) for the same combination into one observation? The search function works well for the sample data, but I need to query about 6 million combinations on a weekly base. Are there other options out there? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: @wake_wake I think `toString` is a good option for collapsing, and a keyed table for looking up multiple pairs at once -- if you have the pairs to query in a table, the neighbors can be looked up in a single join. I've edited to illustrate

Comment: I guess it might be necessary to use `order` when taking the initial `combn` as well and for all pairs to have a < b. Not sure

Comment: It looks like I ran into a similar problem running the first chunk of code: ``Error in `[.data.table`(adjDT_t, , if (.N > 1) { : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed`` . I guess V2 has too many possible combinations that exceed the 2^31 rows?

Comment: Yes, I think it tried to construct a matrix with `nc = choose(.N, 2)` columns and nc had integer overflow and so came back negative (?). You could take an audit of the group sizes with `adjDT[, .N, by=V1][, summary(N)]` or `adjDT[, .N, by=V1][, .N, keyby=.(n_edges = N)]`